# Explore a function for extremums

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have an exam tomorrow and have to know how to explore for extremums a function of 3 variables. For example:

> Explore fo extremums the function: $$f(x,y,z)=x+ \frac{y^2}{4x} + \frac{z^2}{y} + \frac{2}{z}$$

Could someone explain me step by step what I have to do to solve the problem?

Any help, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Think about how you would go about doing this for a situation involving just 1 variable (i.e. f(x) = x^2 +...). Obviously this problem will require finding critical values of the function using the derivative in some way. Perhaps you can then extrapolate that into your current situation dealing with a function of 3 variables... Hint: how might the gradient of this function help you out?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I made a system with three equation with every single derivative(for x, y and z)=0 but I got 3 equations on square. What I have to do next? (sorry for my English)

Comment: you need to set all three partial derivatives equal to 0 and see what critical values you can come up with.  Once critical points are found, you need to find the $3\times{3}$ Hessian matrix which is all of the second derivatives...

Comment: I already have done it, but on the first step I got equation on square and don't know what to do next. Have I to explore more than 1 case?

Comment: what do you mean "on square"...what are the equations?

Comment: sorry for my bad english :( . $$y^2 = 4x^2$$,$$\frac{2y}{4x}=\frac{z^2}{y2}$$ and $$\frac{2z}{y}=\frac{2}{z^2}$$

Comment: so from the first, $y=2x$ or $y=-2x$.  Try substitutiion to get these down to two and then one variable to find critical points.

Comment: Be very careful to not forget that when you take the square root of  a variable, you must add the + or - in order to make sure you have not lost any roots.

Comment: ok, thanks. I thought that there was another way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From $f_x(x,y,z)=0$, $f_y(x,y,z)=0$ and $f_z(x,y,z)=0$ we find $(\frac12, 1, 1)$ and $(-\frac12, -1, -1)$. Since for $x,y,z>0$
$$f(x,y,z)=x+\frac{y^2}{4x}+\frac{z^2}{2y}+\frac{z^2}{2y}+\frac{1}{2z}+\frac{1}{2z}+\frac{1}{2z}+\frac{1}{2z} \ge 8 \sqrt[8]{\frac{1}{2^8}}=4=f\left(\frac12, 1, 1\right)$$
the function has a local minimum at $(\frac12, 1, 1)$. Similarly $(-\frac12, -1, -1)$ is a point of local maximum.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have one more question - Why x,y,z must to be greater than zero?

Comment: I didn't say they must. You need to check the inequality in the definition of local minimum only for points in some neighborhood of $(1/2,1,1)$ and hence you may consider only positive values.

Comment: So if I solve the problem with only positive values for x, y and z all will be ok, right?

Comment: No. How do you explore a function for extremums? You find stationary points and then check whether they are maximum or minimum (or none). In general, you have to investigate the Hessian matrix, but for some particular functions you can check this directly. Recall the definition of local minimum and note that $\{(x,y,z) \colon 0<x<1,\ 0<y<2,\ 0< z< 2\}$ is a neighborhood of $(1/2,1,1)$.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it :)